# Will Gravitational Wave ripple permanently alter space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

When Gravitational Waves alter space-time, would that change be permanent? Will the space-time returns to its initial state once the ripple has stopped?

Comment: [Detecting gravitational-wave memory with LIGO: implications of GW150914](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.01415) - *It may soon be possible for Advanced LIGO to detect hundreds of binary black hole mergers per year. We show how the accumulation of many such measurements will allow for the detection of gravitational-wave memory: a permanent displacement of spacetime that comes from strong-field, general relativistic effects.*

Answer (score -1):

There is something called gravitational memory from gravitational radiation. A gravitational wave may pass a region with some test masses. The ripple in space will cause their relative distances to change. However, there is nothing which says the test masses must return to their initial positions. This is the result of BMS translations [1] which illustrates some deep connections between quantum mechanics and spacetime.

It is illustrative for physical understanding to consider a linearized form of gravitational memory.  In gravitational wave detection this is most likely to be the form gravitational waves and any memory effect will be observed. Gravitational memory from a physical perspective is the change in the spatial metric of a surface according to
$$
\Delta h_{+.\times}~=~ \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}h_{+,\times}(t)~-~\lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty}h_{+,\times}(t).
$$
Here $+$ and $x$ refer to the two polarization directions of the gravity wave.  See [2] for a more complete treatment.  Let us suppose we treat the gravity wave as a linear form of diphoton or colorless state with two gluons, where each photon (or gluon) has a generic state,
$$
|\Psi_{+,\times}\rangle~=~ |h_{+}(t)~+~ih_\times(t)\rangle~=~\sum_{l=2}^\infty\sum_{m=-l}^l
Y_{lm}[(\theta,\phi)\left(|\uparrow\rangle_+~+~ |\downarrow \rangle_+\right)~-~i(\theta,\phi)\left(|\uparrow\rangle_\times~+~|\downarrow \rangle_\times\right)],
$$
where the arrows indicate the polarization directions according to their respective axes. Bern and Dixon work on gravity-QCD duality this way. The matrix element $H_{+,\times}~=~ |\Psi_{+,\times}\rangle\langle \Psi_{+,\times}|$ describes the interaction of the gravity wave with a quantum particle.  This expanded out is
$$
H_{+,\times}~=~ \sum_{l,l'=2}^\infty\sum_{m=-l}^l \sum_{m'=-l'}^{l'} Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l'm'}(\theta,\phi)\left[\left(|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle_{+\times}~+~|\downarrow \downarrow \rangle_{+\times}\right)~+~i\left(|\uparrow\downarrow \rangle_{+\times}~-~ |\downarrow \uparrow\rangle_{+\times}\right)\right]
$$
This tensor operation sets to zero terms like $| \rangle_{++}$ and $| \rangle_{\times\times}$ as unphysical states.  This matrix contains a gravity wave term $|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle_{+\times}~+~|\downarrow \downarrow \rangle_{+\times}$ plus a scalar term $|\uparrow\downarrow \rangle_{+\times}~-~ |\downarrow \uparrow\rangle_{+\times}$ that again we set to zero.

One might object to this in that there is an operator for the gravity wave, but we do not have states.  However, in the Choy-Jamilkowsky isomorphism \cite{key-5}\cite{key-6} there is a correspondence between states and operators (really operations) $|\Psi\rangle\langle \Psi'|~\rightarrow~|\Psi\rangle\otimes|\Psi'\rangle$ which for the Hilbert space is $H~\rightarrow~ H\otimes H$.  Consequently the matrix pertains directly to states in this scheme.  We then have the matrix 
$$
H_{+,\times}~=~ 
\sum_{l,l'=2}^\infty\sum_{m=-l}^l\sum_{m'=-l'}^{l'} Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)Y_{l'm'}(\theta,\phi)\left(|\uparrow\uparrow\rangle_{+\times}~+~|\downarrow \downarrow \rangle_{+\times}\right),
$$
which corresponds to a state vector $|\psi_{+,\times}\rangle$. This is a linear form of gravitational memory and its quantum mechanical analogue.

[1] A. Strominger and A. Zhiboedov, "Gravitational Memory, BMS Supertranslations and Soft Theorems," http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5745

[2] M. Favata "The gravitational-wave memory effect," $\it Class.~Quant.~Grav.$ $\bf 27$, 084036, (2010) http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3486

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. According to your explanation, gravitational waves may change the positions of massive bodies in the region. However, gravitational waves would not directly change the spacetime itself. So this is no more "gravitational memory" than the effect of any other radiation or wind passing through while moving massive bodies. Perhaps the question should've been better phrased in the empty space. If you believe in gravitational memory in the empty spacetime could you explain its physical meaning without losing it behind unproven formulas that easily can be wrong?

Comment: This seems to be cited verbatim from your paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Lawrence_Crowell/publication/317474343_BMS_Supertranslations_as_Coset_States_SLOCC/links/593b0a670f7e9b33171411ad/BMS-Supertranslations-as-Coset-States-SLOCC.pdf). It would be preferable to acknowledge such self-citations. Additionally, it is technically unclear: The gravitational memory effect computed in your references is **not** quantum, so why are you treating the waves as gluonic states? Why would the matrix $H_{+,\times}$, which is just the projector onto the state describe the interaction?